# Como ocultar parâmetros da URL num site ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma duvida, estudando a concorrência, eu percebi que quando você clica numa imagem dentro do resultado de busca, ou eles passam um parâmetro para a `View`assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai tudo bem, eu consigo fazer, mas não acho legal a `URL` exibe o nome do parâmetro e eu não sei se esse é o padrão de desenvolvimento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro do ASP.NET MVC é possivel passar um parâmetro como se fosse uma view tipo igual essa ultima imagem? Assim acho que fica mais limpo, gostaria de saber o nome desse recurso, pois não consegui encontrar nenhuma palavra chave que remetesse ao assunto.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na documentação do Método [File.Encrypt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.encrypt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Procure por ***rotas MVC*** e como ocultar o ID. Esse link pode te ajudar nisso: http://www.macoratti.net/15/09/mvc_crotas1.htm [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611863/net-mvc-4-routing-with-custom-slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611863/net-mvc-4-routing-with-custom-slugs)